# Validity of OCI card when new passport was issued more than 3 moths ago

Tags: visa

I have a US passport. I got my OCI card after the age of 55. I have,since then, obtained a new US passport with a number that is different than the one shown in the OCI card. It has been more than a year ago that I got the new passport.
Do i need to get a new OCI card to go along with the new passport?

Comment: What does OCI mean?